# websocket-rails: Server emits http:// protocol; client expects ws:// protocol

Tags: websocket, websocket-rails

From [Using the JavaScript Client](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Using-the-JavaScript-Client):

> Notice the lack of a protocol prefix on the server URL. Do not add http:// or ws:// to the URL that you pass to the new dispatcher. WebSocketRails will choose the best available transport for you and prepend the correct prefix automatically.

I'm using WebSocketRails for the first time. I'm getting this error in the client:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

If I navigate my browser to `http://localhost:3000/websocket`, I get the messages that I am expecting. If I navigate to the `ws` URL, I get `ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME`. So it appears that the server is producing the messages, but the client is trying the wrong protocol.

How do I force the client to use the `http` protocol rather than `ws`, or force the server to broadcast it with `ws` rather than `http`?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer by digging into the source code. The second parameter of the constructor is called `use_websockets` and defaults to `true`. Setting it to `false` apparently forces it to use `http` instead of `ws`.

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket',false);
```

Comment: Took me a while to find this answer. It doesn't work for me otherwise.